# Open cover with no finite subcovers for the set [0, ∞)

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am trying to find an open cover with no finite subcovers for the set $[0, \infty)$

I am thinking 
union from $n=1$ to $\infty$ of the sets $(0,n)$

Does this work or does this give me $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Well, if it worked, which of these sets includes $0$?

Comment: for sake of clarity, please state the space you consider.

Answer (score 1):

Try $\{[0,n) \; | \; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.  Alternatively, if you're looking for open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ and not in the subspace topology, you can use $\{(-1,n) \; | \; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: it is not open in $\mathbb R$. However open in sub space tropology of $[0, \infty)$....

Comment: Yes, exactly right.  Is that problematic for you in some way?

Comment: it is not clear, whether OP is about $\mathbb R$ or $[0, \infty)$. Not exactly your problem, but @user256017's.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&(-1,1)\\
&(\phantom-0,2)\\
&(\phantom-1,3)\\
&(\phantom-2,4)\\
&\phantom{-n}\vdots\\
&(\phantom-n,n+2)\\
&\phantom{-n}\vdots
\end{align*}